# Why won't windbg disassemble half of my function?

Tags: windbg, disassembly

Background: I'm using windbg to diagnose causes from minidumps from Microsoft's WinQual service. I've taken the time to set things up properly with PDBs and binaries in the same path location as when they were built, and I've had very good luck with windbg and this setup.

Today I ran across a minidump where I'd really like to look through the disassembly to understand the problem, but windbg will only reverse a section of the function.

My function looks like this:

```
SomeStruct* STDCALL getThing(int id)
{
    S_ASSERT(a);
    S_ASSERT(b);
    S_ASSERT(c);
    SomeStruct* result = fn(id);
    S_ASSERT(d);
    return result;
}
```

`S_ASSERT` is our macro which eventually calls into a function, where the `int 3` instruction is hit, even in release builds. I just can't tell which one was hit without inspecting the disassembly.

Using windbg, I can jump to `getThing`in the call stack, activate disassembly and see some code, but can't scroll back in the disassembly. I then added a watch on `module!getThing` to get the function address, and wrote that address in the disassembly window. Instead of instructions, I get ~100 lines of ??? followed by some disassembly which does not look like the function entry point but does look like part of the correct function. It looks like this:

```
No prior disassembly possible
module!getThing:
1d7d4aa0 ??              ???
1d7d4aa1 ??              ???
1d7d4aa2 ??              ???
...
1d7d4b0a 087d1c          or      byte ptr [ebp+1Ch],bh
1d7d4b0d 8b4004          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+4]
1d7d4b10 8bf9            mov     edi,ecx
1d7d4b12 83e11f          and     ecx,1Fh
1d7d4b15 bb01000000      mov     ebx,1
...
```

So, how can I convince windbg to show the rest of the disassembly? Alternately, am I misinterpreting the results? Is there some other software able to load minidumps aside from Visual Studio?

Thank you for any insight you can provide!

Comment: it might be that the dump only has the stack and directly accessible memory (tiny one), can you check what information does the minidump you're inspecting store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have a copy of the **same** dll or exe in the symbol path (`.sympath`) or the exe path (`.exepath`).    Use `!sym noisy` and `.reload` and verify that windbg finds this dll.

Comment: The lm command shows that my exe (where the crash occurs, where the function I can't fully reverse lies) loaded private pdb symbols. I do get a timestamp warning, but the internal build signature must match because it loads automatically.

Comment: Loading the DLL is different from loading the symbols although both use similar mechanisms to find files.  The symbols give you mapping between addresses and symbols (and type info and line numbers, etc.).   The DLL is required because minidumps do not contains the full process memory.   The debugger needs a copy of the original DLL in order to read that memory.

Comment: I thought you were wrong, but in fact you were entirely correct. I didn't think I would see any disassembly if the EXE wasn't found, but the minidump must contain a little more than expected. Copying the EXE to a location in the search path fixed the issue. Thanks! Also sorry for the delay, my work life is busy.